# How do i set the active tab in Primefaces tabView?

Tags: java, primefaces, menubar, tabview

I have a menubar in which two items on a submenu, both calling the same page:

```
<p:menubar autoSubmenuDisplay="true">  
   <p:submenu label="Perfil">  
       <p:menuitem value="Editar" url="perfil.xhtml" />  
       <p:menuitem value="Ver" url="perfil.xhtml" />  
   </p:submenu>  
</p:menubar>
```

In that page i have a tabview with two tabs:

```
<p:tabView dynamic="true">  
    <p:tab id="ver" title="Ver perfil">  
        <ui:include src="verPerfil.xhtml" />    
    </p:tab>  
    <p:tab id="editar" title="Editar perfil">   
    <ui:include src="editarPerfil.xhtml" />  
    </p:tab>  
</p:tabView>
```

How can i set the active tab, so each menuitem activate the corresponding tab?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to do this.You can't use the `url` in the `p:menuitem` because we must call a method to changing the tabindex **before** skipping to the `prefil.xhtml` page. If you use the `url`, the method will be invoked after we skip to  the `prefil.xhtml` page .

First, you can use the action field of the `p:menuitem`, the method returns the address you want to skip to:

```
<p:menubar autoSubmenuDisplay="true">  
    <p:submenu label="Perfil">  
        <p:menuitem value="Editar" action="#{some.editar}" ajax="false"/>  
        <p:menuitem value="Ver" action="#{some.ver}" ajax="false" />  
    </p:submenu>  
</p:menubar>
```

These two method do something to change the tabindex like this:

```
public String editar() {
    tabindex = 0;
    return "verPerfil";
}

public String ver() {
    tabindex = 1;
    return "verPerfil";
}
```

Then the `p:tabView` has an attribute named `activeIndex`. It is the index of the active tab, its default value is `0`. So you can do as follows:

```
<p:tabView dynamic="true" activeIndex="#{some.tabindex}" >
    <p:tab id="ver" title="Ver perfil">
        <ui:include src="verPerfil.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="editar" title="Editar perfil">   
        <ui:include src="editarPerfil.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Then each menuitem will activate the corresponding tab.

Comment: great, thanks! it's still not working, activeIndex="#{some.tabindex}" is not getting the index right but i get the idea and i'll work it from here.

Comment: Ok, Richard's solution wasn't working beacuse of my bean's scope. it was viewscoped. I changed it to SessionScoped and worked like a charm.