# Page redirect issue in Primefaces Tab?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Here is the code which i am trying to run

**ChildTemplate.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition template="../templates/home-template-new.xhtml" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="primeface_default.css" />
        <p:tabView dynamic="true" cache="true" id="tabView">
            <p:tab title="A">
                <ui:insert name="equipList">
                    <ui:include src="../AList.xhtml" />
                </ui:insert>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="B">
                <ui:insert name="terminationList">
                    <ui:include src="../BList.xhtml" />
                </ui:insert>
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Here is the **BList.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.fetchTemp()}" var="temp" reflow="true" resizableColumns="true" liveResize="true"
    id="table2">
    <p:column>  
          ........ 
          ........
    </p:column>
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <div class="divTableFooter" align="right" id="footerDiv6">
            <p:panelGrid>
                <p:commandLink id="create"
                    action="#{bean.methodName()}">
                </p:commandLink>
                <h:link value="LinkName" outcome="AddRecord" />
            </p:panelGrid>
        </div>
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
</ui:composition>
```

Now let me define the problem

Right now my active tab is **B** and when i am clicking the `<p:commandLink/>` or  `<h:link />` It is redirecting and showing tab **A** while it should show **AddRecord.xhtml** page in current active tab `B`.

What is wrong with my code ? Can someone suggest it?

Comment: Please improve your question. It is not an [mcve]. You mention 'AddRecord.xhtml' but it is nowhere. You have a template that is nowhere (does it play a role? No? Remove it)... Your code contains many basic issues (`action="bean.methodName()"`. Start with something simple and make that work first.

Comment: This is typo `action="bean.methodName()"` and if you checked the question thoroughly you will get i already mentioned `<h:link value="LinkName" outcome="AddRecord" />`  .If Basic mistake would be there how could be page rendered? So You can say some typo is there but not basic mistakes.

Comment: Not all 'basic' mistakes make the page not render... And the 'AddRecord' is indeed an omission on my side, sorry for that. And if there are such typos, I'm not investigating further. Anything could be a typo (how can I tell the difference between a typo and basic mistake? Create an mcve that is fully 100% what you run and not some partial copy/paste/edit...

Comment: What does the anchor tag display for viewSource in  <h:link value="LinkName" outcome="AddRecord" />. Please add activeIndex attribute in p:tabView and point it to #{bean.activeIndex} activeIndex should be int in your properly scoped managedBean, so that current tab is not hidden if page or partial page is re-rendered.

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar Any example you know.

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to to another inside the tab B itself?

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar Yes right i am doing same after method call its showing active tab first one

Comment: when u click on second tab is it showing AddRecord.xhtml?

Comment: Yes Right but inside this second tab i have button when i click on this then its not showing other page its showing first tab again.

Comment: It is not a good way to navigate. but i am not getting the answer i need What i am asking is 1. You clicked second tab 2. You clicked button inside it. 3. It shows same page with first tab.  after this, do the following steps. a). click on second tab. IS it still showing button or addRecord.xhtml

Comment: a). click on second tab. IS it still showing button or addRecord.xhtml ? It is showing addRecord.xhtml page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i set the active tab in Primefaces tabView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514352/how-do-i-set-the-active-tab-in-primefaces-tabview)

Comment: As stated earlier, waaaay to much noise in this question and looking at the accepted answer, I'm proven right... Pure duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514352/how-do-i-set-the-active-tab-in-primefaces-tabview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `activeIndex` attribute to your `tabview` component and write a `tabchange` event using `p:ajax` .Please check the below code

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="primeface_default.css" />
        <p:tabView dynamic="true" cache="true" id="tabView" activeIndex="#{bean.tabIndex}">
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{bean.onTabChange}"  />
            <p:tab title="Equipment"  >
                <ui:insert name="equipList">
                    <ui:include src="../AList.xhtml" />
                </ui:insert>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="Termination">
            <ui:insert name="terminationList">
                    <ui:include src="../BList.xhtml" />
                </ui:insert>
            </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
```

in your bean define `tabIndex` variable and implement the `onTabChange` method

```
private boolean popupEdit;
public final void onTabChange(final TabChangeEvent event) {
    TabView tv = (TabView) event.getComponent();
    this.tabIndex = tv.getChildren().indexOf(event.getTab());
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: If this is really just what the OP 'just needed, the question contained waaaaaay to much noise. The whole template stuff does not play a role. The addRecord page loading in tab B still won't happen since there is a full page 'get' request to 'addRecord'.and it then is a plain duplicate... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514352/how-do-i-set-the-active-tab-in-primefaces-tabview